# Import items file in another script in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to do the following:

1. A spider scrapes the links present on the webpage of a website.
2. It saves the links in a text file.
3. Another spider now opens the text file and reads the links and scrapes the individual web pages and saves the data.

I am trying to call these spiders from another python script `which resides in a different directory`. Now the first spider is being called correctly without any issues.
The problem is with the second spider.

The source code of the second spider is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from dateutil.parser import parse
import requests
from scrapy.http import Request
from project-name.items import Project-nameItem

url_list = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        url_list.append(line)
for i in range(0, len(url_list)):
    url_list[i] = url_list[i].replace('\n','')
indexList = [] 
URL = "http://www.exaple.com/id=%s"
number = 0

class AnotherSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "another"

    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    start_urls = [URL % number]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in url_list:
            yield Request(url = URL % i, callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        #scrape the page for the required information
```

When I call the second spider, the error that I get is:

```
runspider: error: Unable to load '/home/project-name/project-name/spiders/anotherspider.py': No module named project-name.items
```

**EDIT**

Since the python script is in a different directory, I am using the `runspider` command to execute the spiders. The problem with this command is that it is a global level command, which means, the project settings are not considered. This is most probably leading to the python script not being able to identify the `items.py` file

The command used to execute the spiders is as follows:

```
scrapy runspider spider1.py

scrapy runspider spider2.py
```

Is there a work around?

Comment: please show source of second spider

Comment: what is the procedure used to invoke the second spider ?

Comment: @aberna simply calling `scrapy runspider spider-name` from the script.

I am using runspider since I am using another script to call the spider programs, And for that I need global commands. But then, since the command is global, I cannot add project specific files. Is there an work around?

Comment: if the spiders are within the same project have you tried using the command "crawl" instead of "runspider" ?

Comment: @aberna I edited my previous comment to throw some more light on the error. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have items.py in any subfolder of project-name?

Comment: My project structure is something like:
`project-name/project-name/items.py`

And for the spiders:
`project-name/project-name/spiders/both the spiders`

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava Then do you have this module in this structure?

Comment: @m170897017 there you go. hope this helps.

Comment: @m170897017 I have edited the question to provide more details.

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava You'd better post the command you use to execute the spiders. BTW, did my answer work for your previous problem?

Comment: @m170897017 Edited as you instructed. and no, it did not work.