# Scrapy multiple spiders

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have defined two spiders which do the following:

**Spider A:**

1. Visits the home page.
2. Extracts all the links from the page and stores them in a text file.

This is necessary since the home page has a **More Results** button which produces further links to different products.

**Spider B:**

1. Opens the text file.
2. Crawls the individual pages and saves the information.

I am trying to combine the two and make a `crawl-spider`.

The URL structure of the home page is similar to:

```
http://www.example.com
```

The URL structure of the individual pages is similar to:

```
http://www.example.com/Home/Detail?id=some-random-number
```

The text file contains the list of such URLs which are to be scraped by the second spider.

My question:

How do I combine the two spiders so as to make a single spider which does the complete scraping?

Comment: what is the difference with this other question you already made 3 hours ago ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020360/import-items-file-in-another-script-in-python

Comment: @aberna There I was calling both the spiders from a separate python script. Now I am trying to combine both of them. Which essentially means I don't have to call them separately.

Comment: instead of writing the links to a file, why not send them as request again ?

Comment: How to do that? Any example illustrating the same on any other question?

Comment: @Udy any examples illustrating the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [scrapy documantation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spiders):

> In the callback function, you `parse` the response (web page) and return either `Item` objects, `Request` objects, or an iterable of both. Those Requests will also contain a callback (maybe the same) and will then be downloaded by Scrapy and then their response handled by the specified callback.

So what you actually need to do is in the parse method (which yuo extract the links there, for each link, yield a new request like:

`yield self.make_requests_from_url(http://www.example.com/Home/Detail?id=some-random-number)`

- the `self.make_requests_from_url` is already implemented in `Spider`

Example of such:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "my_spider"

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            user_name = Selector(text=response.body).xpath('//*[@id="ft"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("https://example.com/" + user_name)
            yield MyItem(user_name)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

You can handle the other requests using a different parsing function. do it by returning a `Request` object and specify the callback explicitly (The `self.make_requests_from_url` function call the `parse` function bu default)

```
Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_user_page)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Udy. I was able to send the request to the other page. But the problem is that the same spider code is run for the requested page too. Which is a problem since the second page has different elements than the home page and I am getting `element not found` error since the element is not present. How do I go about this?

Comment: you can handle this according to the `url` or the `context` of the page.

Comment: Added another option of handling the parsing of different url types.